# Facebook Login for Web in Flask

Tags: flask, facebook-login

While using Facebook api in my website for logging in. There is an error "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions." 
kindly help [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDnHY.png)

Comment: Please, share your code with us.

Comment: @Yaron , the error is not about bug in the code but the Facebook Developer App Configuration..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are logged in Facebook developers.

Select your app and make sure you have admin rights.

In Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email.

And in 'App Review' Tab : change

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?
`Yes`

Then, your app will be live..